# How to get a user's manager by python LDAP or Django LDAP?

Tags: python, django, ldap

I mean i can get some info of vzhong@microhard.com by below code

```
import ldap

connect = ldap.initialize('ldap://ldap.example.com')
connect.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
connect.simple_bind_s('username@example.com', '****password***')

result = connect.search_s('dc=microhard,dc=com',
                          ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
                          'userPrincipalName=vzhong@microhard.com',
                          [])
```

But how to get a user's manager?

And is it possible to get user's status (means if have left company)?

------------- UPDATED -------------------
the `result` include a field `manager` means the manager of this user

the `result` include a field `userAccountControl` that can represent the user's status
`512` means normal account 
`514` means disabled account  
More detail please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/useraccountcontrol-manipulate-account-properties

Answer (score -1):

Not sure to understand what you really want to do... But here is some [documentation](https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
And an example of [configuration](https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html)